# CSS layout problem

Tags: html, css

At the top of [this webpage](http://chaletsdesbouleaux.com/), there are two elements in the main content area (white background): an image and a logo box.

The logo box is floated right and the image has a right-margin which is sufficiently large to accomodate the logo box and a little padding. However, if you make your browser window sufficiently narrow, the logo box slides underneath the image. What I would like to happen is that the horizontal space between the two decreases to a minimum of 6 pixels, and if the browser window is made any narrower, horizontal scrollbars appear.

Is there any way that I can achieve this without resorting to a completely 'frozen' layout, i.e. setting a fixed width on the main content area?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css `min-width` property does what you want. Doesn't work in IE 6, though. For that some JavaScript can help out if it's really necessary.

Set the white DIV's `min-width` to the size of the image + the border.

Comment: Glad to help anyone design a fluid-width layout :)